# Remote query, view and where clause performance

Tags: sql-server

I'm a bit puzzled over a performance problem with our SQL server when using remote query's and applying a where clause. When I run the query on the local server a clustered index seek is used, but from remote this is not the case.

So when running this on the local server it will take 2 seconds:

```
SELECT * FROM uv_order WHERE order_id > '0000200000'
```

But running this from a remote database takes 2 minutes:

```
SELECT * FROM RemoteServer.data.dbo.uv_order WHERE order_id > '0000200000'
```

Here `uv_order` is a quite complex view but since an index seek is used when executing from the local server I don't see why it can't use it when running a remote query. This only seams to apply to view since doing the same thing on a table will work as expected.

Any ideas why this happens and how to "fix" it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can fix it like this

```
select *
from openquery(
    RemoteServer,
    'select * from data.dbo.uv_order WHERE order_id > '''0000200000''''
)
```

Comment: You did beat me for 30 Seconds ;-)

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! its still strange that the optimizer can't handle this case.